# C# -Event Handler -Passing value from one form to another

Tags: c#

I am developing window application POS. Requirement is: when user click on button `'seach item'` on `_mainform(form 1)` then it open `_Searchform(form2)` and on the search form it display result in `listview` with select item button on form3 and close `_searchform(form2)`. The item that we selected from `listview` , we add in `_mainform(form1) listview`.

I try to implement this functionality with delegate and event. On  `form3` (search result form) i have declared delegate and event and subscribe that even on form1(main form). but when i run application event on `form 1` dot get fired.

following this code:

```
 _mainform(form1):

        namespace KasseDelegate
{

    public delegate void ListViewUpdatedEventHandler(object sender, ListViewUpdatedEventArgs e);
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form3 frm3;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frm3 = new Form3();
            frm3.ListViewUpdated += new ListViewUpdatedEventHandler(Frm3_ListViewUpdated1);

        }

        private void Frm3_ListViewUpdated1(object sender, ListViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.Show();

        }

    }
}



_searchform(form2) :




  public partial class Form2 : Form
        {

            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from varer where varenummer=@Varenummer", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Varenummer", "101");

                    SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    Form3 frm3 = new Form3(dr);                            
                    frm3.Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

form 3:

```
namespace KasseDelegate
{

    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public event ListViewUpdatedEventHandler ListViewUpdated;
        SQLiteDataReader dr1;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public Form3(SQLiteDataReader dr)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dr1 = dr;
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dr1 != null)
            {

                while (dr1.Read() == true)
                {
                    ListViewItem LVI = new ListViewItem();
                    LVI.SubItems.Add(dr1[0].ToString());
                    LVI.SubItems.Add(dr1[1].ToString());
                    LVI.SubItems.Add(dr1[2].ToString());
                    LVI.SubItems.Add(dr1[3].ToString());
                    LVI.SubItems.Add(dr1[4].ToString());
                    listView1.Items.Add(LVI);

                }
            }



        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {



            string sVareNummer = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
            string sBeskrivelse = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
            string pris = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text;
            string enpris = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text;
            if (ListViewUpdated != null)
            {
                ListViewUpdated(this, new ListViewUpdatedEventArgs() { VareNummer1 = sVareNummer, Beskrivelse1 = sBeskrivelse, Pris1 = pris, Enpris1 = enpris });
            }


        }
    }
    public class ListViewUpdatedEventArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
        private string VareNummer;
        private string Beskrivelse;
        private string pris;
        private string enpris;
        public string VareNummer1
        {
            get
            {
                return VareNummer;
            }
            set
            {
                VareNummer = value;
            }
        }
        public string Beskrivelse1
        {
            get
            {
                return Beskrivelse;
            }
            set
            {
                Beskrivelse = value;
            }
        }
        public string Pris1
        {
            get
            {
                return pris;
            }
            set
            {
                pris = value;
            }

        }

        public string Enpris1
        {
            get
            {
                return enpris;
            }
            set
            {
                enpris = value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So how i can get values of listview selected item from form3(displayitem) to form1.(mainform).

Comment: YOUR SHIFT KEY IS STUCK. OOPS. MINE, TOO.

Comment: Its hard to understand "frmVelgVarer" and "Varesøk". Which one is form2 and which one is form3 ?

Comment: there are three forms. On form1, There is Button to search item. when user click on that button it open form2 where user can search items with name , id . when user fill name or id and click search button it open form3 with results in listview. so i want when user select item from that listview (form3) and click select then it will add that selected item from form 3 to form one listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up an event in your `Form3` and access it from outside like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        Form3 new3 = new Form3();
        // Access the event of form3 from outsite
        new3.DisplayedItemChanged += ItemChanged;
    }

    public void ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This will be triggered.
    }
}

public class Form3 : Form
{
    // Create an event
    public event EventHandler DisplayedItemChanged;

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DisplayedItemChanged != null)
        {
            // Raise the event and pass any object
            this.DisplayedItemChanged(yourObjectToPass, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**According your comments below:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        // This one is an instance of Form3
        Form3 newForm = new Form3();
        newForm.SomethingHappens += RaiseHere;
    }

    public void RaiseHere(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        // This one is NOT the same as on Form1. Its a NEW form.
        Form3 newForm = new Form3();
        newForm.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler SomethingHappens;

    public Form3()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**This wont work, never.** You have to use the same instance:

```
Form3 newForm = new Form3();
newForm.SomethingHappens += RaiseHere;
newForm.Show();
```

If this isnt clear for you I cant help, sorry:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Reply! There is three forms. On form1, There is Button to search item. when user click on that button it open form2 where user can search items with name , id . when user fill name or id and click search button  it open form3 with results in listview. so i want when user select item from that listview (form3) and click select then it will add that selected item from form 3 to form one listview.

Comment: Then this example still provides everything you need. Just set up events for form2 and form3. Hook form2 to the event of form3 and form1 to the event of form2.

Comment: but can i access then event of form3 to form1 . when i try to do this then my event remains null and i got error.

Comment: What exactly is `Null` in here? You need to access the event with the instance of your form3. Then everything should work.

Comment: When i access event of form3 to form1. for Exampel form3 frm3 = new form3() , frm3.ListViewUpdated += Listviewupdated; then i got null refrence error.

Comment: Actually, on form1 event does not get subscribed that is y it get null. but if i subscribe on form 2 then it get subscribe and does not null. How i can solve it. plzzzzzz

Comment: Cant tell. They problem comes from your code. Delete the subscription from form2 and only set it on form1. Maybe its overwriting the subscription if set twice.

Comment: Thanks for ur help friend! I have deleted but tried every thing. but i am trying. Thanks for help i realy appriciate that

Comment: I have uploaded all my three forms can u have a look plz. when i subscribe on form 2 then it get subscribe but on from 1 it dot get subscribe. thanks in advance

Comment: On `form1` you just create `form3` but you never show it. Where is your `form3.Show()`??

Comment: i create form3  to access event(frm3.ListViewUpdated += Frm3_ListViewUpdated;)  and then i create show form3 from form2 to show it.

Comment: But on `form2` there is ANOTHER `form3`? If its NOT the same instance as on `form1` it wont work.

Comment: On form 1 i create form3 instance for access event and on form2 i create form3 instance to show form3.  Bez i can not show form3 from form1. from form1 i can show form2 and from form2 i can show form3. sorry for confusing and thanks for ur time

Comment: Yep there is your problem dude. You create 2 instances. One on `form1` (access event) and one on `form2`. They are NOT the same. Its like when you have 2 cars. If you crash the windows of car1 they wont be broken for car2. They are both cars, but not the same instances.

Comment: You have to hook the event on the very same instance where you show the form with form.Show();.

Comment: so that means where i create then instace of form and show. only in that form i can subscribe event not on multiple forms.   i am new to window application not complete understand that is problem as well . thank alot for your time my friend i really appriciate ur reply nd time

Comment: I've edited my answer. Maybe I can create a small picture to visualize it for you for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly you have `Form1` - which launches `Form2` which in turn launches `Form3`. On selecting some item on `Form3` you need to update it back on `Form1`.

So declare a delegate on `Form1`. Pass this delegate to `Form2` [`Form2` constructor should accept this as a default parameter - so that if `Form2` is triggered from some other place we need not have hard dependency on delegate.]

maintain a private variable of this delegate type on `Form2` and while launching `Form3` pass the same delegate to `Form3` constructor.

On `Form3` you have the delegate now which is holding a reference to a method on `From1`, so whenever an item is selected you can assign this delegate on `Form3` which will fire the method on `Form1`.

so here is an working example.

```
 public delegate void MyDelegate(string selectedItem);
public class Form1
{
    private MyDelegate delegate1;

    public Form1()
    {
         delegate1 = new MyDelegate(ShowSelectedItem);
         var form2 = new Form2(delegate1);
    }

    public void LaunchForm2()
    {

    }

    private void ShowSelectedItem(string result)
    {

    }
}

public class Form2
{
    private MyDelegate form2Delegate;

    public Form2(MyDelegate del = null)
    {
        form2Delegate = del;
        var form3 = new Form3(form2Delegate);
    }

    public void LaunchForm3()
    {

    }


}

public class Form3
{
    private MyDelegate form3Delegate;

    public Form3(MyDelegate del = null)
    {
        form3Delegate = del;
        SelectedItemTriggered("tes");
    }

    public void SelectedItemTriggered(string selectedItem)
    {
        form3Delegate(selectedItem);
        //This will trigger method ShowSelectedItem of Form1

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Vishal . Thanks for help . I am very new to delegates and window application.  i have explain scenario below :                                                                
Thanks for Reply! There is three forms. On form1, There is Button to search item. when user click on that button it open form2 where user can search items with name , id . when user fill name or id and click search button it open form3 with results in listview. so i want when user select item from that listview (form3) and click select then it will add that selected item from form 3 to form one listview

Comment: Hi Seeker, For your convenience I have a small example.please refer.

Comment: Hi Vishal ! Can u plz have a look on code now plz. when i subscribe on form 2 then it get subscribe but on from 1 it dot get subscribe. thanks in advance

Comment: Hi seeker, I will update my existing code, I have added few more details. I have tested it, it should work.